# Fastest way to copy values between two matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am looking for a fastest way to copy some special value of a matrix to other matrix. Assume that I have matrix A such as

```
A =[4     1     5     4     4
   -2    -1     1     2     2
    3    -1     1     7     3
    5     3    -1     1    -2
    6     4     4    -1     1]
```

My aim is that copy element that have value 1 and -1 to matrix B. The expected matrix B such as

```
B =[ 0     1     0     0     0
     0    -1     1     0     0
     0    -1     1     0     0
     0     0    -1     1     0
     0     0     0    -1     1]
```

I performed two way to create matrix B. However, I think that my way is still not fastest way if size of matrix A becomes larger. I know that the forum has many expert matlab guy. Could you suggest to me another way?
This is my code

```
%%First way:
tic;B=((A==1)|(A==-1)).*A;toc
Elapsed time is 0.000026 seconds.
%%Second way:
tic;idx1=find(A==1);idx2=find(A==-1);B=zeros(size(A));B(idx1)=1; B(idx2)=-1;toc;B
Elapsed time is 0.000034 seconds.
```

Comment: Your first method is the canonical solution. Before you start trying to optimize it, please try this on a matrix of a similar size to those in your application to see if you really do need to optimize this further or not. That you only "think" it is not the fastest way indicates you are optimizing prematurely

Comment: for such fast times better use `timeit`, but for such small matrices even that is problematic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's somthing on par with @thewaywewalk

```
B=A.*reshape(abs(A(:))==1,size(A));
```

This is how I test these:

```
A=randi(10,1000,1000)-7;
B1=@() ((A==1)|(A==-1)).*A;
B2=@() (abs(A) == 1).*A;
B3=@() A.*reshape(abs(A(:))==1,size(A));


timeit(B1)
ans =
0.0136

timeit(B2)
ans =
0.0080

timeit(B3)
ans =
0.0079
```

These will change from run to run, but the methods are on par...
here's the same test on a range of matrix sizes:

[image]

Comment: Thank bla and thewaywewalk. I think that your way is fastest.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing which comes to my mind, which could be faster:

```
B = (abs(A) == 1).*A;
```